# Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64

Tags: c#

For some reason ZipFile.Open started to generate "Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64". The zip file is valid and the code used to work before.

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
```

Comment: Was it zipped using 7z?  I find Windows has issues reading 7z archived .zips on occasion.

Comment: What is the full traceback of the exception?  How many separate objects in the ZIP file?

Comment: There is 1 file inside the archive and it was archived using UNIX gzip

Answer (score 4):

I too got the same error while running the code, and I tried to open that particular zip file from windows - it didn't open. Tried with 7-zip then also same. Then FTPed the file from the server where I did before and it started working. So I feel that something is wrong with the zip file. Try by using the original zip file from server or check is the zip file is not corrupted.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this exception was thrown at reading a copied ZIP file. It turned out I copied the ZIP file the wrong way, using

```
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.**WriteTextAsync**(storageFile, 
File.**ReadAllText**(sourceFileInfo.FullName));
```

instead of

```
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.**WriteBytesAsync**(storageFile, 
File.**ReadAllBytes**(sourceFileInfo.FullName));
```

Answer (score 2):

> There is 1 file inside the archive and it was archived using UNIX gzip

If the archive isn't a `ZipFile` (`.zip`), but rather a `GZip` (`.gz`) you shouldn't use `ZipFile`. You should use `GZipStream` inside the `System.IO.Compression` namespace.

If it is a `.tar.gz` (sometimes `.tgz`) and not a vanilla gzip (`.gz`) file, you will need to get a 3rd party library to extract it, such as [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) or [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error while trying to read the zip content as an Object.
Different micro service sends it to my service.

I figured that I used the wrong Deserialize format.
I always used UF8 encoding but sometimes I got byte array so UT8 damaged the file.
We fixed it by getting a header from the previous micro service that tells me the object type.

Bottom line, make sure you using the right decoder!