# Function App Deployment on Premium Subscription

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a function app from VS code into Azure.

Each time I attempt to deploy, I receive this stack:

```
2:48:04 PM xxxx: Verifying that app settings have propagated... (Attempt 1/12)
2:48:06 PM xxxx: Starting deployment...
2:48:06 PM xxxx: Creating zip package...
2:48:06 PM xxxx: Zip package size: 14.7 kB
2:48:19 PM xxxx: Fetching changes.
2:48:20 PM xxxx: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/2e4c7760-ec95-404f-81f5-9b373121bb6b.zip (0.03 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
2:48:20 PM xxxx: **Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.**
2:48:34 PM xxxx: Deployment failed.
```

Here's what is strange:

The same exact code works when I deploy it to Azure from VS Code when the function App is behind a consumption tier, but spit of the error above on the premium tier.

I have looked through other articles, and cannot find a solution to the problem.

Related Forums:

- [Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081900/number-of-entries-expected-in-end-of-central-directory-does-not-correspond-to-nu)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1462401/azure-functions-deployment-error-number-of-entries

One article mentions to install Azure Function version 1.12.4, after which the stack becomes

```
7:31:39 PM xxxx: Starting deployment...
7:31:40 PM xxxx: Creating zip package...
7:31:40 PM xxxx: Zip package size: 19.7 kB
7:31:46 PM xxxx: Fetching changes.
7:31:48 PM xxxx: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/9530b5ab-378f-45e5-81f8-960e490dd5f6.zip (0.02 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
7:31:48 PM xxxx: **Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64**.
7:31:54 PM xxxx: Deployment failed.
```

I have also looked through articles related to this error and cannot find a solution.

Related Forums:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1164071/vs-code-deployment-error-offset-to-central-directo
- [Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423322/offset-to-central-directory-cannot-be-held-in-an-int64)
- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/3348
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1462400/error-while-deploying-a-function-on-azure-through

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

In summary, I tried

- Restarting the function
- Stopping then starting function App
- Changing Azure Function Version
- Creating a Brand new Function
- Change Azure Function Tier
  I expected the deployment to be successful

**Update #1:**

I used VSCode Function App Extenstion Version 1.13.0 and the deployment went through but now the functions don't show up in the Azure Portal.

This is the end of the stack:

```
7:59:39 PM xxxx: Deployment successful. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
8:00:03 PM xxxx: Syncing triggers...
8:00:19 PM xxxx: Querying triggers...
8:00:28 PM xxxx: No HTTP triggers found.
```

I experienced this in the past when I declared local variables in the script of the function app, removing those while using Function App Extension 1.13.1 AND a function app on a premium version solved the problem. I will be reviewing and will update if I find a solution. What a pain in the neck!?

Here are some related articles:

- https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1774
- [Azure Function Deployment Successful but Triggers are not synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810499/azure-function-deployment-successful-but-triggers-are-not-synchronized)
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/2529
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators#update-app-settings

**Update #2:**
Interestingly enough, when I add a try block on the importing of the packages I receive this new error: Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory which makes me think the root of issue has to due with the package dependencies.

**Update #3:**
I noticed one of the libraries I imported "os" was greyed out, so I removed it, and the error went away. After 5 minutes of deploying I received the following stacktrace:

```
8:24:08 PM xxxx: Syncing triggers...
8:25:04 PM xxxx: Syncing triggers (Attempt 2/6)...
8:25:21 PM xxxx: Syncing triggers (Attempt 3/6)...
8:25:43 PM xxxx: Syncing triggers (Attempt 4/6)...
8:26:23 PM xxxx: Syncing triggers (Attempt 5/6)...
8:27:44 PM xxxx: Syncing triggers (Attempt 6/6)...
8:28:34 PM: Error: Encountered an error (ServiceUnavailable) from host runtime.
```

**Update #4:**

After restarting the function app, I now get this error.

```
8:38:39 PM xxxx: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/0321ff98-e4cb-4baf-bf3d-829aa0cea78f.zip (0.00 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
8:38:39 PM xxxxx: Central Directory corrupt.
8:38:53 PM xxxxx: Deployment failed.
```

This is insane how difficult it is to deploy a simple code. There has to be reasonable solution that does not require chasing error after error....

**Update #5:**

I tried deploying using Azure Core Tools. I get a Success message, however the function are missing in the portal. Noting I deployed the sample function Azure/VS Code provides.

More details on how to deploy using core tools below.

[Deploying Azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952891/deploying-azure-function)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azps-windows?view=azps-11.1.0&tabs=powershell&pivots=windows-psgallery

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant "xxxxxxxx" -SubscriptionId "xxxxxxxxx"

How to find Tenant ID

- [How to get the azure account tenant Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384034/how-to-get-the-azure-account-tenant-id)
  Follow this path: Microsoft Entra ID > Default Directory > Properties

How to find Subscription ID
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/get-subscription-tenant-id
Follow this path: Subscriptions

func azure functionapp publish

**Update #6:**

This article suggested version changes on some extension in VS Code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1462400/error-while-deploying-a-function-on-azure-through?comment=answer-1391559&page=1#comment-1459936

I applied the changes but it results in 8:52:55 AM: Error: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime, even after restarting the function multiple times.

**Here is my local.settings.json**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxx",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

**Here is my import statement of the libraries:**

azure-functions
pyodbc
requests
uuid

**Here is my import statement of the libraries:**

[import statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZaZJ.png)

Comment: Are you deploying Python Azure function?

Comment: Yes I am using python.

Comment: Please provide your `local.settings.json` and `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Also, try deploying with Azure function core tools using command `func azure functionapp publish <functionappname> --build-remote true`.

Comment: I added the local.settings.json and requirements.txt to update#3 in the post.
I have also tried deploying using the command, resulting in same issue.

Comment: Is this Python v2 function?

Comment: Yes Python V2, thank you

Comment: Try deploying the same to a new function app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issues when I was trying to deploy the Python V2 Function to Azure with the packages:

```
azure-functions
pyodbc
uuid
requests
```

I have replicated the same in my environment as below:

- Created a Python V2 Http Triggered Azure Function.

**requirements.txt:**

```
azure-functions
pyodbc
uuid0
requests
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_connection_string>"
  }
}
```

- **Added the below application settings in Azure Function App's Configuration in portal.**

```
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags = EnableWorkerIndexing
```

- Deployed the function to Premium Azure Function App successfully using Azure Function Core Tools with the command:
  `func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name>`

**Console Response:**

```
C:\Users\<username>\kpyv2fn>func azure functionapp publish functionappname
Getting site publishing info...
[2023-12-14T12:23:22.451Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Deleting the old .python_packages directory
Uploading 2.37 KB [###############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id '5ec0XX2-c'.
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running oryx build...
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /tmp/build/expressbuild --platform python --platform-version 3.11 -i /tmp/8dbfc9f7e1ada4c -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20230508.1, Commit: 7feXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX4592, ReleaseTagName: 20230508.1

Build Operation ID: 19XXXXXXXXXXXbb5
Repository Commit : 5ec05XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX9ae36591
OS Type           : bullseye
Image Type        : githubactions

Detecting platforms...
Detected following platforms:
  python: 3.11.6

Using intermediate directory '/tmp/8dbfc9f7e1ada4c'.

Copying files to the intermediate directory...
Done in 0 sec(s).

Source directory     : /tmp/8dbfc9f7e1ada4c
Destination directory: /tmp/build/expressbuild

Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.6/bin/python3.11
Creating directory for command manifest file if it does not exist
Removing existing manifest file

Running pip install...
Done in 3 sec(s).
[12:23:42+0000] Collecting azure-functions
[12:23:42+0000]   Using cached azure_functions-1.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (165 kB)
[12:23:42+0000] Collecting pyodbc
[12:23:42+0000]   Using cached pyodbc-5.0.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (344 kB)
[12:23:42+0000] Collecting uuid0
[12:23:42+0000]   Using cached uuid0-0.2.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
[12:23:42+0000] Collecting requests
[12:23:42+0000]   Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
[12:23:42+0000] Collecting pybase62
[12:23:42+0000]   Using cached pybase62-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
[12:23:42+0000] Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
[12:23:42+0000]   Downloading idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
[12:23:43+0000] Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
[12:23:43+0000]   Downloading charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (140 kB)
[12:23:43+0000] Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
[12:23:43+0000]   Downloading certifi-2023.11.17-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
[12:23:43+0000] Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1
[12:23:43+0000]   Downloading urllib3-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
[12:23:43+0000] Installing collected packages: urllib3, pybase62, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, uuid0, requests, pyodbc, azure-functions
[12:23:43+0000] Successfully installed azure-functions-1.17.0 certifi-2023.11.17 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 idna-3.6 pybase62-1.0.0 pyodbc-5.0.1 requests-2.31.0 urllib3-2.1.0 uuid0-0.2.7
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.11.6/bin/python3.11 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Not a vso image, so not writing build commands
Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/tmp/build/expressbuild'...
Done in 0 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.
Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.

Done in 3 sec(s).
Writing the artifacts to a Zip file
Running post deployment command(s)...

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
```

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pravallika

I tried pushing via Azure Core tools while having the portal configured as you stated, and received a success message however the function are missing from the portal. 

End of stack below.

Generating summary of Oryx build
Deployment Log file does not exist in /tmp/oryx-build.log
The logfile at /tmp/oryx-build.log is empty. Unable to fetch the summary of build
Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!

Comment: Did you change the package `uuid` to `uuud0`?

Comment: That fixed it! THANK YOU!

Comment: Accepted, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Wow.  uuid0 fixed it for me too.  Microsoft really needs to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

I want to share what worked for me.

#1 Install the following extension versions. Thanks to **JananiRamesh-MSFT** in this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1462400/error-while-deploying-a-function-on-azure-through?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1391559#newest-answer-comment

Azure App Service Version: 0.25.0

[image: Azure App Service Version]

Azure Function Version: 1.12.4

[image: Azure Function Version]

Azure Resource Version: 0.8.0

[image: Azure Resource Version]

#2 Pay careful attention to the importing of libraries and requirements.txt. I was using uuid but the requirements.txt needs to have uuid0. I have no clue why but **Pravallika KV** pointed this out.

**Import:**

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
try:
    import pyodbc
    import json
    import uuid
    import requests
    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    from datetime import datetime
    import traceback  # Import the traceback module
    import time
    import random
except:
    pass
```

**Requirements:**

```
azure-functions
pyodbc
requests
uuid0
```

After these 2 were solved I was able to deploy directly from VS code.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the issue at my end I am checking with internal team on this and will update you here once I hear back from them.

Meanwhile try decreasing the version of Azure Resource extension,

Following settings worked for me:

Azure Resources -> v0.8.0

[image]

refernce threads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1462400/error-while-deploying-a-function-on-azure-through

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1462401/azure-functions-deployment-error-number-of-entries